# Java regular expression to get a value in matlab

Tags: regex, matlab

Hi I was wondering how I can do this in matlab: I have a file and somewhere in the file i have this string = **"1 to 10 of 434M"** . I would like to get the **"434M"**. Though keeping in mind that the M can also be other letters (K or B), but is always a capital letter. The ciphers before the letter can be up to 3 chippers, but can also be smaller.

How would I get this out of a text in matlab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that you read your file line by line. Then for each line execute the following commands:

```
% line is current line of input file
[matchstart,~,~,~,tokenstring] = regexp(line, '1 to 10 of (\d+[MKB])');
if ~isempty(matchstart)
  desired_string = tokenstring{1};
end
```

This regular expression matches at least one digit before `M`. (E. g. also 451274M) If it should only match numbers with 1 to 3 digits use:

```
'1 to 10 of (\d{1,3}[MKB])'
```